# How to retrieve a list of events using Mircrosoft Graph API?

Tags: android, microsoft-graph-api

I want to show logged user's list of `events` using Microsoft Graph via Android. I have followed all the instructions and added required permission from both Android side as well as Microsoft.

I am using following details :

```
final static String SCOPES[] =  { 
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read", 
    "Calendars.ReadWrite", 
    "Calendars.Read",
    "Calendars.Read.Shared",
    "Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared"
    };
final static String CALENDER_URL =
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$select=subject,body,bodyPreview,organizer,attendees,start,end,location";
```

Comment: What is the issue you see?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to leverage the [android sdk](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-android) which is a wrapper around all the service call. This will allow to leverage a few things like: strong types, error handling, serialization, auto-completion...
Here is some [detailed documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/android).
Then the code will look something like that:

```
graphClient
.getMe()
.getCalendar()
.buildRequest()
.get(...)
```